# How to hide <iframe> if the embedded video url is blank in rails app ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, youtube, show-hide

This must be very simple. But I just can't seem to find the proper solution.

I have a model with an embedded video attribute.

I made it happen like this:

```
 On my show page
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= @trip.youtube %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Everything works fine, but the thing is that i don't want to show this part if the youtube url is blank. Otherwise I am left with a huge white space, which I don't need.

I've tried to play around with **unless** or **if** conditions

```
 <% if @trip.youtube.blank? %>
  <iframe width="0" height="0" src="<%= @trip.youtube %>" frameborder="0" class="hidden" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <% else %>
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= @trip.youtube %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <% end %>
```

But I'm doing something wrong.
 Any suggestions for a better way ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
<% if @trip.youtube.present? %>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= @trip.youtube %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<% end %>
```

And leave it at that?

Answer (score 0):

aaa... such a dumb mistake.

In my _form I had:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :youtube %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :youtube,:value => 'http://' %><br />
 </div>
```

Since the field had already - **http://**, either way, with or without youtube url, rails didn't identify it as blank  :))

needs to be simply:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :youtube %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :youtube %><br/>
  </div>
```

and

```
 <% if @trip.youtube.present? %>
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= @trip.youtube %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <% end %>
```

Works like a charm. Thanks :)